# Plotly: How to assign a unique name to each point in a box plot?

Tags: python, plotly

Let's say I want to analyze the exam grades of some students during a course. I have the following data:

```
    grade subject student
0       2    math    Mike
1       3    math    Mike
2       2    math    Mike
3       8    math   Susan
4       9    math   Susan
5       7    math   Susan
6       3     art    Mike
7       2     art    Mike
8       4     art    Mike
9       7     art   Susan
10      8     art   Susan
11      7     art   Susan
```

At first sight, I am interested in studying globally my dataset. For example using Plotly's Box Plot:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

exam_grades = [2, 3, 2, 8, 9, 7, 3, 2, 4, 7, 8, 7]
subjects = ['math', 'math', 'math', 'math', 'math', 'math', 'art', 'art', 'art', 'art', 'art', 'art']
students = ['Mike', 'Mike', 'Mike', 'Susan', 'Susan', 'Susan', 'Mike', 'Mike', 'Mike', 'Susan', 'Susan', 'Susan']

df = pd.DataFrame({'grade':exam_grades ,
                   'subject': subjects,
                   'students': students})

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Box(y=df.loc[df['subject'] == 'math']['grade'], name='math'))
fig.add_trace(go.Box(y=df.loc[df['subject'] == 'art']['grade'], name='art'))

fig.update_traces(boxpoints='all', boxmean=True)
fig.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Ok, now my problem. I can clearly see that there are two different subgroups in each subject. I am interested in knowing from which student is each particular point for further analysis. This would give me an idea of what is going on in order to choose a more proper way to divide and plot the data. In my example, I could know that each subgroup is related to a particular student.

So far, I have only found the Plotly's option "text" so the hover label will show a string. But this string will be the same for all points of each box plot.

What do you suggest?

Comment: How did my suggestion work out for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Displaying the student name on hover for each point is easy enough. But if you are *really*

> interested in knowing from which student is each particular point for further analysis

and would like to

> know that each subgroup is related to a particular student.

then it's going to be really cumbersome to hover over each point looking for matching student names. In my humble opinion, the optimal way to display this would be to assign a color for each student so that any grouping would be more visually distinguishable. And this *is* possible with plotly.express straight out of the box:

**Plot 1:**

[image]

**Code 1:**

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

exam_grades = [2, 3, 2, 8, 9, 7, 3, 2, 4, 7, 8, 7]
subjects = ['math', 'math', 'math', 'math', 'math', 'math', 'art', 'art', 'art', 'art', 'art', 'art']
students = ['Mike', 'Mike', 'Mike', 'Susan', 'Susan', 'Susan', 'Mike', 'Mike', 'Mike', 'Susan', 'Susan', 'Susan']

df = pd.DataFrame({'grade':exam_grades ,
                   'subject': subjects,
                   'student': students})

fig = px.box(df, x="subject", y="grade", points="all", color='student')
fig.show()
```

But if you don't like that particular split by student within subject, perhaps this is more to your liking:

**Plot 2:**

[image]

This certainly is ***not*** straight out of the box. Here I've hacked together two different `px.Scatter` figures with students identified by unique colors into one, and then added two `fig.add_traces(go.Box())` to include the box plots and make sure they werent split by including the color grouping.

This can be made a lot more flexible with regards to the number of students and subjects. And I'd be happy to do that. But not until you let me know if this is something you could use.

**Code 2:**

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np

exam_grades = [2, 3, 2, 8, 9, 7, 3, 2, 4, 7, 8, 7]
subjects = ['math', 'math', 'math', 'math', 'math', 'math', 'art', 'art', 'art', 'art', 'art', 'art']
students = ['Mike', 'Mike', 'Mike', 'Susan', 'Susan', 'Susan', 'Mike', 'Mike', 'Mike', 'Susan', 'Susan', 'Susan']

df = pd.DataFrame({'grade':exam_grades ,
                   'subject': subjects,
                   'student': students})

# math
fig1 = px.scatter(df[df['subject']=='math'].reset_index(),
                 x=np.random.uniform(low=-0.04+0, high=0.04+0, size=len(df[df['subject']=='math'])).tolist(),
                 y="grade", color="student",
                 #size='petal_length',
                 hover_data=['subject']
                )
# art
fig2 = px.scatter(df[df['subject']=='art'].reset_index(),
                 x=np.random.uniform(low=-0.04+1, high=0.04+1, size=len(df[df['subject']=='art'])).tolist(),
                 y="grade",
                 color="student",
                 #size='petal_length',
                 hover_data=['subject']
                )

# Combine figures
fig = go.Figure(data=fig1._data)
fig.add_traces(data=fig2._data)
fig.add_traces(go.Box(y=df.loc[df['subject'] == 'math']['grade'], name='math'))
fig.add_traces(go.Box(y=df.loc[df['subject'] == 'art']['grade'], name='art'))

# customize legends
for i in range(0, len(fig['data'])):
    if type(fig['data'][i]['customdata'])!=type(None):
        fig['data'][i]['name']=fig['data'][i]['customdata'][0][0]+fig['data'][i]['name']

fig.update_layout(title = 'Subjects, students and grades',
                  yaxis_title="Grades",
                  xaxis_title="Subjects",
                  )
fig.update_xaxes(tickfont=dict(color='rgba(0,0,0,0)'))

fig.show()
```

Comment: Hi. Code 1 is being useful for a first analysis and better understading of what is going on. But I am very interested in Code 2 for a nice final in deep analysis, thanks.

Comment: @eliteA92 Glad to hear that! Don't hesitate to let me know if you've got further questions. And please consider marking one of the two contributed answers as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can set patameter text with list of student names, here is an example:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Box(y=df.loc[df['subject'] == 'math']['grade'], name='math', text=students))
fig.add_trace(go.Box(y=df.loc[df['subject'] == 'art']['grade'], name='art', text=students))
```

on mouse hover:

[image]

Comment: I think it's a nice and easy approach to my problem. For a first analysis it's fairly good. For a more complicated analysis, I will try to elaborate vestland's approach. Thanks!